# Git Commands on PowerShell Script - Authorization

Tags: c#, git, powershell, azure, tfs

I have a question about what best to do in this situation. I want to write a script that creates a local repository and then can fetch and push from a VSTS to TFS to create a backup.

Using GIT Bash i was able to make this work following the instructions below.

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/repository-to-mirror.git
cd repository-to-mirror.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror
```

I want to make a Powershell script with ISE on windows 10 that also does this. I installed git-posh to be able to write commands.

But when I write commands as instructed by GIT (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)

```
    git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

I get error:

remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Logic-Test1.git does not exist or you do not have 
permissions for the operation you are attempting.

Username: : The term 'Username:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

How to do the authentication so I can clone it? Also, is there a way of not having to type the authentication for every command?

Answer (score 2):

This blog [Script to clone all Git repositories from your VSTS collection](https://blog.rsuter.com/script-to-clone-all-git-repositories-from-your-vsts-collection/) provides an example on how to clone a git repo from VSTS using powershell, you can check it and follow it for other commands.

First, create a PowerShell script file:

```
# Read configuration file
Get-Content "CloneAllRepos.config" | foreach-object -begin {$h=@{}} -process { 
    $k = [regex]::split($_,'='); 
    if(($k[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($k[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True)) { 
        $h.Add($k[0], $k[1]) 
    } 
}
$url = $h.Get_Item("Url")
$username = $h.Get_Item("Username")
$password = $h.Get_Item("Password")

# Retrieve list of all repositories
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$gitcred = ("{0}:{1}" -f  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($username),$password)

$resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri ("{0}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=1.0" -f $url)
$json = convertFrom-JSON $resp.Content

# Clone or pull all repositories
$initpath = get-location
foreach ($entry in $json.value) { 
    $name = $entry.name 
    Write-Host $name

    $url = $entry.remoteUrl -replace "://", ("://{0}@" -f $gitcred)
    if(!(Test-Path -Path $name)) {
        git clone $url
    } else {
        set-location $name
        git pull
        set-location $initpath
    }
}
```

Then create a config file alongside your script with your configuration:

```
[General]
Url=https://myproject.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection
Username=user@domain.com
Password=YourAccessToken
```